# Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account

Tags: support, stack-overflow, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

I can't post any questions to Stack overflow, a message keeps coming:
**Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.**

I went through a lot of similar posts on meta.stack overflow and found out some of the reasons for it.
But surprisingly, *none of the reasons apply [to me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355722/jatin).*

I started answering questions frequently, since last month and most of the answers were accepted, if not accepted then upvoted.

I remember, I deleted 1-2 questions when I created my account, but that was quite before.

Only one of my questions asked, has been closed uptil now, and that too because the answer was subjective, not because the question was irrevelant or asked poorly.

What is the reason behind this ban?

Comment: Did you also see [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this) I still think that should cover all; if not then please let us know what is not clear so we can improve it?

Comment: Are you sharing an IP address with others? (Or using some shared computers, as you're an under grad student?)

Comment: stuff like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642812/group-together-all-the-anagrams plus all your deleted questions (I count 12, not "1 or 2") .. not a good combination.

Comment: @Arjan: It seems very harsh to me that this was closed as a duplicate. Jatin explained nicely why he does _not_ consider it a duplicate; he obviously has done some research before asking.

Comment: @Jeff: I'd say it's unfair to quote his **only** question with a negative score.

Comment: @hendrik it wasn't negative when I posted it. and no I did not downvote it.

Comment: @Jeff: Ah, OK, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: (@Hendrik, I did not even vote to close `;-)` That aside, Jatin did not state if he read that specific question, and unfortunately was not around to respond to the comments. Anyway, Jeff has taken a look, and surely has considered wether or not this is a good ban.)

Comment: @Arjan: I pinged you of all people since there was noone else I could ping at the moment of writing that comment `:-)` I was just interested in your opinion since you already had had a look. (I should have formulated my comment more carefully, though.)